# Need help rewriting domain redirect rule

Tags: .htaccess

Recently I started getting Google Search Console errors for page redirects.

```
http://my-domain.com/
http://www.my-domain.com/
https://www.my-domain.com/
```

I have the following rule in my .htaccess file:

```
# remove www and turn on https in the same rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

I've had it for a while but I guess Google has changed something on their side. How can I modify the rule to avoid the penalties?
[image]

Comment: What kind of errors?

Comment: @Justinas It's not the code error - it's Google's penalty for doing a such redirect.

Comment: So it states that it will simply skip these URL's from google indexing and will only index final page, because you will never be in them anyway. So you either remove redirect or live with it.

Comment: And you provided error message, even if it's validation error